При ивенте on_message() не работают другие команды discord.py
from discord.ext import commands
import os
import discord
intents = discord.Intents.all() 
intents.message_content = True
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = "!", intents=intents)

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('Бот запущен!')

@client.command()
async def ping(ctx, message):
    await ctx.send('pong')
    
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    print('dfdfdffd')

client.run("")

Уже второй день ломаю голову, при ивенте он месадж не работают другие команды, без него все работает

Добавьте строку в конец функции on_message:
await bot.process_commands(ctx)

Пример здесь.

Спасибо большое!
